# Update ( subquery ) set ..... expression in MariaDB ( MySQL)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I am trying to convert MS Sql stored procedures to MariaDB stored procedures.

This is a part of Mariadb ( Mysql ) Stored procedure that I converted as following:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tt_tmpTable;  
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tt_tmpTable
   (
      FNewID VARCHAR(11), 
      FOrderID VARCHAR(10), 
      FMasterYN VARCHAR(1),
      FpcherCd VARCHAR(5), 
      FpcherNm VARCHAR(50), 
      FvndCd VARCHAR(7), 
      FvndNm VARCHAR(50), 
      FStep VARCHAR(5),
      FrequestDt VARCHAR(8), 
      FConfirmDt VARCHAR(8), 
      FAmount NUMERIC(21,2), 
      FitemCd VARCHAR(6), 
      FitemNm VARCHAR(100),
      Fqty INT, 
      FCost NUMERIC(21,2), 
      FTotalCost NUMERIC(21,2), 
      FAddAmt NUMERIC(21,2), 
      FAddMemo VARCHAR(255), 
      FItemDiv VARCHAR(20),
      FMemo VARCHAR(255)
   );

        UPDATE (select FOrderID FID, sum(FTotalCost) FAMT from tt_tmpTable where FMasterYN = 'N' group by FOrderID) t 
        set tt_tmpTable.FAmount = t.FAMT where FOrderID = t.FID;
```

but it didn't work and get an error as "Error Code: 1288
The target table t of the UPDATE is not updatable".

So I am wondering if anyone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to declare tt_tmpTable as "t" (see below)...

```
SELECT FOrderID AS FID, SUM(FTotalCost) AS FAMT FROM tt_tmpTable t WHERE...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE tt_tmpTable JOIN
       (select FOrderID, sum(FTotalCost) as FAMT
        from tt_tmpTable
        where FMasterYN = 'N'
        group by FOrderID
       ) t 
       ON tt_tmpTable.FOrderID = t.tt_tmpTable
    set tt_tmpTable.FAmount = t.FAMT  ;
```

Your original query would not work on any database.  It is not possible to update the result of an aggregation.